# How to convert NSData object to file ouput

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone project,I need to convert NSData object to file.I have to convert NSData to file and save on project's resources folder and need to use it.How to save NSData as files and how to reference them on my project as resources?

Comment: Did you even *glance* at the [online documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/) for NSData before asking your question??? (-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NSData** has a function you can call to write it to a file:

```
[nsDataObject writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

where *path* is the path and filename you want to write it to.